# Amazon S3 Compressing Files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

A few years ago I uploaded some photos to S3. When I try to retrieve them today, the files seem to be corrupted, as I am unable to open them in the browser or with a photo editor. Looking at the file properties, it seems the files have been compressed, as there is a `x-amz-meta-compression-algorithm` key with the value `zlib` and a `x-amz-meta-compression-original-size` with a value of `53890`. However, the size of the file on S3 is `53761`. I did not compress the files before uploading them. How can I uncompress these files?

Comment: Whatever you used to upload the files must have compressed them -- because S3  does not do that.  Objects, once uploaded, are immutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you download the file and determine its type using `file` command?

If it is indeed zlib compressed or if `file` command says data, try the accepted answer in this link: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22834/how-to-uncompress-zlib-data-in-unix

```
printf "\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" |cat - zlib.raw |gzip -dc > myfile
```

Comment: `file` says `data`. I tried the answer on the link and it seems to work, but how do I save the file instead of printing it out to the screen?

Comment: @RHPT I have updated the answer. Just redirect the output to a file.