# How to compress a file which is saved on S3 without save to local machine

Tags: amazon-s3

I had to compress and upload a file which is saved on Amazon S3 **without save to local machine**.
If I could save to local machine, I used following bash commands.

```
aws s3 cp s3://myBucket/doc/to/sensitive_file .
gzip sensitive_file
aws s3 cp sensitive_file.gz s3://myBucket/doc/to/sensitive_file.gz
```

But, I could not save. Does anyone know good idea? I can use bash and python.

**What I did**

I read [Amazon S3 Compressing Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36209854/amazon-s3-compressing-files) but I could not solve.

**Environment**

- macOSMojave 10.14.6
- GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18)
- Python 3.6.3

Answer (score 0):

I could compress and upload to Amazon S3 following 3 steps with using python3.

1. Using BytesIO package, get contents and save to variable.
2. Using BytesIO and GzipFile packages, compress contents.
3. Put compressed file to Amazon S3

This is code.

```
import boto3
from io import BytesIO
from gzip import GzipFile


def compress_on_s3(bucket, from_key, to_key):

    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    with BytesIO() as input_buf:
        s3.Object(bucket, from_key).download_fileobj(input_buf)
        input_buf.seek(0)
        data = input_buf.getvalue()

    with BytesIO() as buf:
        with GzipFile(fileobj=buf, mode='w') as gz_file:
            gz_file.write(data)

        s3.Object(bucket, to_key).put(Body=buf.getvalue())


compress_on_s3("myBucket", "doc/to/sensitive_file", "doc/to/sensitive_file.gz")
```